# Error when installed Xamarin.CommunityToolkit: "The target platform must be set to Windows"

Tags: nuget, .net-6.0, maui, .net-maui, xamarin-community-toolkit

I'm trying to install Xamarin.CommunityToolkit(ver. 2.0.5) from Nuget Packages,
but I get this error message:

[image: dependency error]

So I installed Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData with version 2.4.1.1, as it says
then I tried to install CommunityToolkit again, and again I've got the same message but with different compliant.
This time it wants me to install Xamarin.Google.Android.Materia(1.6.0).
I repeated the process a couple of times, and finally I was able to install CommunityToolkit successfully,
but then, when I build the project I get this:

[image: build failure]

I don't know what should I change to get rid of this error, it was working all fine before I installed this CommunityToolkit package

Here's my .csproj file:

### [image: csproj1]

[image: csproj2]

I did try to add "net6.0-windows" to  tag with various combinations, but with no effect.
Problem repeats on a newly created project aswell.
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MAUI use [CommunityToolkit.Maui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Maui) package instead of Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.

- [Official repo](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui)
- [Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/)